# Which characters make use of the haste spell in Final Fantasy 13-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I've been trying to find a reference to the haste spell in Final Fantasy 13-2 but I can't find it anywhere.  It doesn't seem to appear on any of the character spells for Synergist, does it appear on any of the monsters?

Comment: I haven't gotten a Synergist yet in 13-2, but in FF13 Haste was definitely a Synergist spell (a pretty high level one as I recall).

Comment: I don't think there's a castable Haste nor are there +damage buffs. Maybe they are on the monsters? I think you're suppose to rely on weapons/accessories that boost your ATB rate and/or give Auto-Haste. Seems kinda funny that Sarah and Noel can time travel, but they can't cast Haste...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haste, as it existed in *Final Fantasy XIII*, doesn't exist in *Final Fantasy XIII-2*. Instead, the Mog clock is the primary source of haste: if you get a "Great!" rating, you'll get a preemptive strike and start the battle with haste.

There's also a commando auto-ability for monsters, *Haste Feeder*, that casts Haste on the monster automatically.

A number of weapons and accessories that increase the ATB rate:

- *Faerie's Bow*, *Rune Feather*, *Angel's Bow*, *Eurytos's Bow*, and *Indrajit* for Serah
- *Rune Tooth*, *Sargantanas*, *Nomad's Machete*, *Orochi*, and *Romulus & Remus* for Noel
- *Kaiser Knuckles* line of accessories

The *Hermes Sandals* line of accessories also casts Haste when critical.